# difference between CATransform3DTranslate and CATransform3DScale

Tags: iphone, ios, 3d

Pretty naive question. I don't really understand the term 'translate' here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While both are functions that modify a CATransform3D, the modification they perform is different. CATransform3DTranslate moves transforms the coordinate space by moving it in the x,y,z space. If you apply a CATransform3DTranslate to an object's transform (e.g a CALayer) it would change position in the screen. CATransform3DScale will resize the space, making transformed objects bigger and smaller. If you apply a CATransform3DScale to an object's transform is would change size.